# No ClassTag Available (Scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

Something weird is happening with me in Scala. I am trying to use a third party library

`org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils.createDirectStream`

and getting No ClassTag exception. I simulate the scenario below as one can think Util as third party library. Why is this happening?

```
object Util {
    def fun1[K: ClassTag, M: ClassTag, KD: ClassTag, MD: ClassTag]: Unit = {
        println("In function version 2")
    }
}

class ClassTagIssue[K, M, KD, MD] {
    def build: Unit = {
        Util.fun1[K, M, KD, MD]
    }
}

object ClassTagIssue {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        new ClassTagIssue[String, String, String, String]().build
    }
}
```

I am trying to run this code and getting below exception

```
Error:(23, 14) No ClassTag available for K
    Util.fun1[K, M, KD, MD]
             ^
Error:(23, 14) not enough arguments for method fun1: (implicit evidence$1: scala.reflect.ClassTag[K], implicit evidence$2: scala.reflect.ClassTag[M], implicit evidence$3: scala.reflect.ClassTag[KD], implicit evidence$4: scala.reflect.ClassTag[MD])Unit.
Unspecified value parameters evidence$1, evidence$2, evidence$3, ...
    Util.fun1[K, M, KD, MD]
             ^
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to add the `ClassTag` class as a context bound to the generic types of `ClassTagIssue`. That way, you tell the compiler that the `ClassTags` for the types `K, M, KD` and `MD` will be available when a `ClassTagIssue` instance is created.

```scala
class ClassTagIssue[K: ClassTag, M: ClassTag, KD: ClassTag, MD: ClassTag] {
  def build: Unit = {
    Util.fun1[K, M, KD, MD]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Till its working .. it will be great if you can explain whats was the issue...

Comment: The problem is that `Util.fun1` expects implicit values for the types `ClassTag[K]`, `ClassTag[M]`, `ClassTag[KD]` and `ClassTag[MD]` in the calling scope. However, since the concrete types `K, M, KD` and `MD` are unknown, the compiler cannot generate them and have to be passed by the caller in the scope of `ClassTagIssue` and, thus, in the scope of the `build` method. That's effectively what's done by adding the context bounds to the generic parameters of `ClassTagIssue`. Whenever you create a `ClassTagIssue` instance, you also have to provide the `ClassTag` instances for the types.